# NodeJs can't listen to socket.io private channel when active sockets are only one

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am broadcasting connection between nodejs, and flutter...I am emitting to private channel, and listening to the same channel.

I am defining socket.io config in server.js, then, I am using an instance of it @ authcontroller.js.

The issue I am having is that when I try to listen to the private channel from auth.controller, I am receiving the response only when active sockets are more than one socket. However, from server.js, I am receiving the response instantaneously, even with only one socket.

Below is the code:

Server.js

```
    //general dependencies
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
const api = require('../api/AuthController')



var server = http.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is running on port', server.address().port);
});


//routes
const routes = require('../api/routes');
routes(app,io);

//socket config
global.io = io; //added


    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('privateChannelID', function (message) {
            console.log('message received from server.js')

    });
    });
```

AuthController.js:

```
global.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
         socket.on('privateChannelID', function (message) {
                    console.log('message received from authcontoller')

             });
             });
```

Any idea, what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

Frontend code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:adhara_socket_io/adhara_socket_io.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

const String URI = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _MyHomePageState();

  List<String> toPrint = ["trying to connect"];
  SocketIOManager manager;
  Map<String, SocketIO> sockets = {};
  Map<String, bool> _isProbablyConnected = {};
  bool newtripRequest = false;
  var pickupController;
  var dropoffController;
  SocketIO socketController;
  var driver = 'driver';
  String socketIdentifier;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    manager = SocketIOManager();
    initSocket("default");

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }




  initSocket(String identifier) async {
    setState(() => _isProbablyConnected[identifier] = true);
    SocketIO socket = await manager.createInstance(SocketOptions(
        //Socket IO server URI
        URI,
        nameSpace: (identifier == "namespaced") ? "/adhara" : "/",
        //Query params - can be used for authentication
        query: {
          "auth": "--SOME AUTH STRING---",
          "info": "new connection from adhara-socketio",
          "timestamp": DateTime.now().toString()
        },
        //Enable or disable platform channel logging
        enableLogging: false,
        transports: [
          Transports.WEB_SOCKET /*, Transports.POLLING*/
        ] //Enable required transport
        ));
    setState(() {
      socketIdentifier = identifier;
    });
    socket.onConnect((data) {
      pprint("connected...");
      pprint(data);
      sendMessage('news', 'yes', socketIdentifier);
    });

    socket.onConnectError(pprint);
    socket.onConnectTimeout(pprint);
    socket.onError(pprint);
    socket.onDisconnect(pprint);
    socket.on("news", (data) => newTripRquest(data));
    socket.connect();
    sockets[identifier] = socket;
  }

  bool isProbablyConnected(String identifier) {
    return _isProbablyConnected[identifier] ?? false;
  }

  disconnect(String identifier) async {
    await manager.clearInstance(sockets[identifier]);
    setState(() => _isProbablyConnected[identifier] = false);
  }

  sendMessage(privateChannel, messageBody, identifier) {
    //pprint("sending message from '$identifier'...");
    sockets[identifier].emit(driverChannel, [
      {'response' : messageBody}]);
    //pprint("Message emitted from '$identifier'...");
  }

  pprint(data) {
    setState(() {
      if (data is Map) {
        data = json.encode(data);
      }
      print(data);
      toPrint.add(data);
    });
  }
```

**Update:**

AuthConroller.js

```
    'use strict'

    const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
    const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

    var authController = {

    findNearestDriver: function (req, res) {


        var query = Driver.find({
            'geo': {
                $near: [
                    req.body.lat,
                    req.body.lng
                ],
                // $maxDistance: distance

            }
        });
        query.exec(async function (err, driver) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            }

            if (!driver) {
                res.json({});
            } else {



                for (let i = 0; i < driver.length; i++) {

                    global.io.emit(`news${driver[i]._id}`, { 
               pickupLat: req.body.lat, pickupLng: req.body.lng, dropOffLat: 
               req.body.dropLat, dropOffLng: req.body.dropLng });
                    global.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
                        socket.on(`news${driver[i]._id}`, function (message) {
                            if (message.message === 'Accept') {
                                resultRecieved = true
                                console.log('message received')
                            }
                        });
                    });


                }


                res.json(driver);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = authController;
```

Comment: What does `broadcasting` mean in your question?   Can you show the code that calls `.emit()` show whether it's client or server and then explain exactly where you do and don't see that message?

Comment: thanks for your response...I added the front end code. From the frontend, I am emitting to nodejs, using the function (sendMessage), where I emit to a private channel.

In nodejs, I expect to receive the emitted message on the same channel, exactly at this part of the code

global.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
         socket.on('privateChannelID', function (message) {
                    console.log('message received from authcontoller')

             });
             });

Comment: How and where are you loading `AuthController.js:`?

Comment: I am not loading AuthController.js....I am defining the endpoints in the routes, and calling the functions with postman, or frontend....what I am trying to do is basically, call a function in Authconrtoller.js to generate an array of users, and emit to each user in a private channel (using his ID). I am able to emit to each user perfectly fine, but when it comes to receive a message back on the same channel, I only can receive it when the active sockets are more than one.

Comment: There has to be some code somewhere in your server that loads AuthController.js or that code isn't even part of your server, isn't active and isn't hooked up to anything.  I'm trying to figure out if perhaps you're loading it too late so it isn't loaded in time to see the first socket.

Comment: what you are saying makes perfect sense....that's why authcontroller listens to the socket after it is called from the end point....any idea how to run this page when the server starts...I am defining authcontroller in this line in server.js:

const api = require('../api/AuthController')

any idea who to run this page as well when server initiates?

Comment: Can you show where the line `const api = require('../api/AuthController')` is in the general context of your code.  FYI, that line IS "loading" AuthController.js.  That what I was asking for all along.

Comment: I have updated the question with server.js full code

Comment: OK, can I now see the rest of `AuthController.js`?  It appears that you're loading `AuthController.js` BEFORE you set `global.io` so when `AuthController.js` is first loaded, it doesn't have access to `global.io`.  FYI, a cleaner implementation would be to load `AuthController.js` after you initialize socket.io and then pass `io` to that module rather than using the global.

Comment: in authController, I only have few imports (not related to socke.io), like:

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

and, then I have authController, where it contains all the functions, and at the end is module.exports = authController, where I can use it in routes.

I don't import socket.io, I use it directly with global.io

Comment: I need to see the actual code for AuthController.js for the next step in troubleshooting.  Please add it to your question.

Comment: added...thanks for all your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `authController.js`, you have a:

```
global.io.on('connection', ...)
```

that is embedded inside some other function `findNearestDriver()`.  So, that connection event handler won't be active until after `findNearestDriver()` function is called and executes and until after the query inside of it finishes.  This means you will miss any `connection` events that occur before that function is called.

It's also inside a `for` loop which is almost never what you want as that just creates identical, but duplicate event handlers.

Event handlers like `global.io.on('connection', ...)` should generally be near the top level of your module and initialized when the module is initialized, not in a place where they can be run multiple times.

---

Note, you are also loading `authController.js` before `global.io` has a value.  That means you can't just move the `global.io.on('connection', ...)` to the top level of the module unless you also move the `require('authController.js')` to be AFTER `global.io` is set.

But, I think you need a bit of a redesign for how this part of `authController.js` works because `connection` event handlers need to be at the top level of the module, not buried deep inside a `for` loop inside a function.

This nicely illustrates one of the problems with using global variables to communicate things when there are asynchronous operations involved.  It creates frustrating timing or load order problems.  IMO, it would be better to explicitly pass `io` to this module in a module constructor function and use it from there, not from a global.  This would make it a lot less likely that you would code it in a way that tries to use `io` before it is initialized.

Comment: many thanks for your detailed response. I didn't fully implement the solution, but at least I understood where is the issue coming from. I will redesign my modules, and update my question by then